# P & Q are located 20 units apart & R( from a set of points) is located 20 units from P & Q what is the probability that R is closer to P than to Q

Tags: probability

So, I have trouble in understanding this question, I know that for geometric cases of probability we need to find areas; we cannot do so here because this is not one of those types of questions. Any help would be really appreciated on this one.

I thought the answer was this 0. My reason: we know that probability of choosing 1 out 3 points is 1/3, but then we are not doing that we as we are selecting a point from locus of points and we do not know any characteristics of those points. Please help me out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does it mean that $R$ is located $20$ units from $P$ and $Q$?  That the sum of $PR$ and $QR$ is $20$?  Or something else?

Comment: So, this is something that it is not clear in the question itself, I think what you are saying is right. But, if we take that how will we proceed to find out which is point is closer, i.e P or Q ?

Comment: There's not much point in proceeding unless we know what the question is asking.  This is not a detail—it's the central thrust of the question.